# Using python for decoding with different protocols/formats

Tags: python, hex, protocols, decode

I'm wondering what the best way to decode a binary code is in python, if there are various protocols or formats available. For example, if bit 26 = 0, it is protocol "A" but if bit 26 = 1 it is protocol "B". Protocols A and B have totally different bit structures after that point. Additionally, within protocol A and B are other "sub protocols".

The end goal is to pass a hex string to the class, and get out the attributes that the bits define. So I was thinking I would create a class and then sub classes of the different protocols. Does that sound like a good approach?

Additionally, do I need to initialize every possible attribute so that the object is fully-initialized?

TIA

Comment: start writing and you see what you need.

Comment: What are you trying to do that can't be done with bytes.decode()?

Comment: I did start writing and I'm just ending up doing a whole bunch of nested "if" statements.

Comment: @JohnMachin, The decode involves a whole bunch of defined fields. So if bit 25 = 1 and then bits 26 - 28 = '101', then bits 80 - 100 = latitude. Things like that.